# Am I allowed to hide a YouTube video after a user action?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

This question is slightly different from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034835/can-i-hide-a-embeded-youtube-video-or-is-that-against-the-terms-of-use

When a user visits our website, the YouTube player is visible and in the right size. A user can play the video and see the whole video. Nothing fancy. However we want to put the player in a tabbed interface. Meaning that the user can hide the video by going to another tab. For example:

```
Video | Info | Share
```

When the site loads the Video tab is active, but users can click "Info", then the video is hidden while the video keeps playing in the background.

Is this allowed? I would say gray area but I'm not sure. We always show the YouTube logo and link to the YouTube video on youtube.com btw. Also, if a users scrolls down on youtube.com, the user also hides the video and can still hear the audio. Is this perhaps the same area?

Comment: don't see why you cannot, i mean you don't break any rules in the terms of services of YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

This is in their terms of services so i would say it is not allowed

8.separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;

9.promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;

14.use a video player smaller than the minimum video player size set forth in the YouTube API documentation and specifications.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=it

Comment: Thanks, I've read those :). Our purpose of hiding the video is not because we don't want to hide the brand. It just fits better with our interface this way. But perhaps it's too bad..

Comment: Legally it's suggests you shouldn't, realistically i doubt very much that any implications would come your way if you did.